# Database error on inserting data for ABAP type decfloat_16 to DF16_SCL column

Tags: abap

I created a simple transparent table with 3 columns

col1 - type int1

col2 - type df16_scl

col3 - type int2

When I try to programmatically insert data into this table the database always returns an error with the message "Conversion not supported. Source type DECFLOAT and target type VARBINARY". An example row that I tried to insert is `(1, 1.4 , 2)`.

Can anyone please tell why is it saying `VARBINARY` even though the data type is `df16_scl`? And why am I not able to insert any data?

Comment: My system tells me that DF16_SCL is obsolete. Is there a good reason why you don't want to use DF16_RAW or DF16_DEC?

Comment: No particular reason. I just wanted to play around with the data types in abap types and DDIC type :)
One thing to note here is that, the same problem is also present for DF16_RAW

Comment: So at least show us your INSERT, I bet 100 bucks it is wrong

Comment: Because [*DF16_RAW and DF34_RAW](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenddic_decimal_floating_point.htm): In database fields of this type, decimal floating point numbers are stored as binary (in RAW format)* and *obsolete predefined data types DF16_SCL and DF34_SCL ... In database fields of this type, decimal floating point numbers are stored in **the same way** as DF16_RAW or DF34_RAW*